# Where is the icon for shared folders (as seen in "Network") located?

Tags: windows-7, icons, shared-folders

I see this gorgeous icon when going through "Network" that scales up to "very big icons".

But when I access it from the drive and try to customize it, all I can get is a very small and pixelated version from `shell32.dll`. Where can I find that icon?